# When submitting an updated APK, can I force previous versions to be uninstalled?

Tags: android, installation, google-play, apk, uninstallation

I'm submitting an update to my APK on Google Play, and I want any previous versions of the app to be uninstalled before the updated version is installed. Is there any way to make this happen, on a technical level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot require the apk be uninstalled first.  However you can handle this gracefully.  On app start store the app version in `SharedPreferences` then each app start should check if the the version changed.  If the version changed then delete your app's preferences and this should give them a fresh install state.

Comment: What do you mean by "fresh install state" here? It's not the same as uninstalling, right?

Comment: It depends on what your going for.  If you kill all your Alarms and services then delete your app's cache, databases, local storage and preferences  Your app should be in a similar state to when you uninstall and reinstall.  What are you unable to delete that requires a full uninstall?

Comment: The problem is I don't know exactly. I just know that uninstalling first works. It's probably a subtle issue. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Is there a crash? Bad data? What are the symptoms of the issue?

Comment: It looks like this was a very subtle issue indeed due to bad data. I now store the version number in SharedPreferences as you suggested so I can clear old data on upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

No, that depends on the user.

The solution i use is to force update using a server and a version number.
A popup to lock user out.

But why do you need to uninstall?

Worst case you can clear all his data via code.

Comment: I know I can force update but I want to force uninstall. There was a problem with proguard in the previous version. It doesn't seem to be resolved unless I do a clean install.

Comment: I guess I'll have to settle for just asking nicely in the release notes.